# How can I simply assign data from an xml document to a variable?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to c# and using XML in conjunction with it. I simply want to take the data from each "votes" node and assign it in order to seven different int variables using whatever method is easiest (I read that linq is good). I've tried a couple times but most of what I've read is too complicated. I'm also confused as to how I can reference a specific node if there are other nodes with the same name. This is the XML file:

```
    <results>
      <result>
        <name>one</name>
        <votes>100</votes>
      </result>
      <result> 
        <name>two</name>       
        <votes>200</votes>        
      </result>
      <result> 
        <name>three</name>       
        <votes>300</votes>        
      </result>
      <result>
        <name>four</name>
        <votes>400</votes>        
      </result>
      <result>
        <name>five</name>
        <votes>500</votes>        
      </result>
      <result>
        <name>six</name>
        <votes>600</votes>        
      </result>
      <result>
        <name>seven</name>
        <votes>700</votes>        
      </result>
    </results>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey, you should add the code you have for parsing the XML into a data structure so we know what XML framework is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and easy using Linq.

(Use `XElement.Load` to load a file instead of parsing a string.)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace so61208822
{
    class Program
    {
        static string xmlData = @"
<results>
  <result>
    <name>one</name>
    <votes>100</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>two</name>
    <votes>200</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>three</name>
    <votes>300</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>four</name>
    <votes>400</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>five</name>
    <votes>500</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>six</name>
    <votes>600</votes>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>seven</name>
    <votes>700</votes>
  </result>
</results>
";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var root = XElement.Parse(xmlData);
            var votes = root.Descendants("result").ToDictionary(i => (string)i.Element("name"), i => (int)i.Element("votes"));
            foreach(var vote in votes) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} votes", vote.Key, vote.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs e.g.

```
one: 100 votes
two: 200 votes
three: 300 votes
four: 400 votes
five: 500 votes
six: 600 votes
seven: 700 votes
```